# CIDetectorTypeQRCode typed CIDetector doesn't instantiate properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, qr-code, core-image, cidetector

I try to scan a QR code from an image with the following code.
Basically my problem is that "prepareQRCodeDetector" returns nil (at least on iPhone 5s, didn't test on another device yet)

Notice that CIDetectorTypeFace returns a working CIDetector.

In the documentation, it's said that the feature is available from iOS 8

```
    //iOS CoreImage QR Detector
- (CIDetector *) prepareQRCodeDetector {
    return [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode context:nil options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh}];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    if (image != nil){
        //AVFoundation QRCode detection
        CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage options:nil];
        NSString * decodedAccountName = @"";
        CIDetector * detector = [self prepareQRCodeDetector];
        if (detector != nil) {
            NSArray<CIFeature*> *features = [detector featuresInImage:ciImage];
            for (id feature in features) {
                decodedAccountName = ((CIQRCodeFeature *)feature).messageString;
            }
            [self openUserProfileByAccountName:decodedAccountName];
        }
    }
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm facing the same problem. My code is working on iOS 9 but the detector is nil on iOS 8. And like you said, the Apple documentation says the feature is available since iOS 8.

Comment: unfortunately no. I didn't solve this problem.

Comment: Same issue with me, It is working in iPhone but issue in iPad.

Comment: Same Issue here , Not working in iPhone also

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35885137/cidetctor-always-remains-nil-cant-read-qrcode   Please answer this