# CIDetctor always remains nil, Cant read QRCode

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code, core-image, cidetector

I cannot initialize CIDetector for reading QRCOde , It always remains nil. Here is my code :

```
let options = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh]
            self.detector =  CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeQRCode, context: nil, options: options)
```

If I replace `CIDetectorTypeQRCode` with `CIDetectorTypeRectangle` it get initialized but I need to read QRCode

I am trying from last two days, Please help

Answer (score 0):

Finally got that working:

Follow the steps:

1. Select XcodeProject
2. Select Target
3. Select BuildSettings
4. Make Sure ValidArchitecture have arm64 or replace it with (arm64 armv7 armv7s)

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post.